# Local Storage function appending unnecessary values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using Eric Hynd's multiselect widget and storing it to local storage with other html elements. My function is automatically storing "class_id" and setting the value equal to the last value in the drop downs, which is 6.

Could I just write a few lines to ignore `multiselect_` when the function comes across it?

something like `if($(this).attr('multiselect_')){
                        return false;`

Please see my fiddle for the problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/3u7Xj/130/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `$(this)` is referring to a named input, you could easily do with a regex `match`:

```
if(this.name.match(/^multiselect_/)){
   return false;
}
```